# How can I list videos in android app using YouTube API in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, video, youtube, youtube-api

How do I list videos from a YouTube channel using YouTube API? I've created a project, I have the `YouTubePlayerApi` in my project and I have a `API` key, but I can't find a tutorial that shows how to use it. The tutorials I've seen have either been inaccuarate or really hard to follow along and understand.

Comment: you can add what you tried, please post the "hard" to follow part, that will easy to get answer!

Comment: @mig_santos121 ok, thx, i'll try.. do you have any recommendation on a tutorial? The "hard" part is too find a tutorial that does the thing i want.. there should be a tutorial on how to list videos from youtube, right?

Comment: @mig_santos121 Iv'e completed [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1214971/Youtube-channel-integration-in-Android-using) tutorial but it didnt work.. I have a really hard time to understand the YouTube Google Developers examples and tutorials..

Comment: @mig_santos121 oh, i every time i try to use the link to get json or whatever i always get this error: "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 470213383779 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=470213383779 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=470213383779"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Java sample in [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list):

```
// Sample java code for videos.list

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
        parameters.put("id", "Ks-_Mh1QhMc");

        YouTube.Videos.List videosListByIdRequest = youtube.videos().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
        if (parameters.containsKey("id") && parameters.get("id") != "") {
            videosListByIdRequest.setId(parameters.get("id").toString());
        }

        VideoListResponse response = videosListByIdRequest.execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```